# Restricting access for Sitecore Administrator

Tags: security

We are having one problem to hide access to Template Manager, security editor and access Viewer option for a user with sitecore Administrator Role.

To do this we denied read access for only select user with Administrator Role for to hide. But it is not working.

Answer (score 8):

"Administrator" users cannot be denied anything. They have access to everything by design. If you want to restrict access you'll need to add your user(s) to a custom role: define your own role (how-to [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/create_and_set_up_a_role)) and set the desired security on that role (by adding it to other roles and by denying access to items - preferably by breaking the inheritance).

An overview of the available security roles is available [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles). You can use those to get the base of your custom role.

Answer (score 7):

Security restrictions are never applied to users that a marked as administrators. If you really need to achieve the desired behavior then you should not make the user as the administrator, and assign all necessary roles and deny necessary rights.